# How to convert HBITMAP to BYTE array for JNI

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi+

first of all sorry by my bad english, Hello i am new in this kind of forum, the question i have is a headache, well i still looking for everywere in this page and other, i can't no find the solution, first i need to create a screen capture and save it in a jpeg byte array, my code is simple and create the HBITMAP but the trouble is convert it to an array, here is my code:

```
int takeScreenShoot(){
GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
ULONG_PTR gdiplusToken;
GdiplusStartup(&gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL);

HDC screenDC,memDC;
HBITMAP screenBITMAP;
screenDC= GetDC(NULL);
memDC= CreateCompatibleDC(screenDC);
int Height = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);
int Width = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);
screenBITMAP = CreateCompatibleBitmap(screenDC,Width,Height);
BitBlt(memDC,0,0,Width,Height,screenDC,0,0,SRCCOPY);

/*
  use GDIplus for transform the image to JPEG and pass to a byte stream
  or somethig like that
*/
ReleaseDC(NULL,memDC);
ReleaseDC(NULL,screenDC);

return 0;
```

}

well, this code if for practice, i try to use Image class from GDI+ and also Bitmap but i don't find the way to save it in a byte array, in some pages talk to use IStream but is dificult to me understand it, i need someone to direct me in the right way, thanks beforehand for the help :D

Comment: I don't understand the question - `HBITMAP` is a Windows native handle so not likely to be useful in Java code.  Why do you need to marshal this as `BYTE[]`?  Do you actually wish to send the bitmap itself into Java code as a `BYTE[]`, using the `HBITMAP` somehow to achieve this?

Comment: yes, well the idea is that HBITMAP have a screenshot image in it, i need to send that image over network using java, so i cant pass the hbitmap directly to java over JNI as an object i need is pass his byte data and use java to convert it in an bufferedImage, in this case as jpeg encoded image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for [GetDIBits](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144879%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)?   Convert a dependent bitmap into a [DIB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183562%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) and then stream it into an array or file or whatever you want.

There are several image libraries that can help give ideas as well.  [CxImage](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/cximage.aspx), [FreeImage](http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/), all have functions to convert HBITMAP (both DDB and DIB) into a stream-o-bytes.

Comment: very thanks for your response, one question more, you have any example for conver the CxImage to an array in JPEG format?

Comment: See `CxImage::GetBits()`.   It returns a pointer to the bitmap bytes directly.   You can MemCopy()/memcpy() that out into your own BYTE[].

Comment: And if you want to get a stream of bytes encoded as JPG, CxImage could help with that too.   You could convert your HBITMAP to a CxImage object (see CxImage::CreateFromHBITMAP), then Encode(CxFile .., CXIMAGE_FORMAT_JPG) it to a JPG.   CxFile() allows you to write to an actual FILE, or just a blob of memory (see CxMemFile).   With the heavy lifting being done by CxImage you could do this in just a couple lines of code.   You'll have to add CxImage + libjpeg to your library though.  We use CxImage in our project and it works nicely.   Good luck!

Comment: thanks @CoreyStup, i really glad you help me, i im try to use the Cximage library but i have some problem on the linker, i'm using Dev c++ with the library cximage.lib bun in the moment of compile there is linker errors like:   [Linker error] undefined reference to `CxImage::CxImage(unsigned int)', i'm sorry if i become tiring but i'm still so near and i learn more thank's to this :)

Comment: i need help, i never use static libs in C++, how this work and wath i need?

Comment: thanks a lot for the help finally a get to use CxImage in my proyect :D